# Keras RL not implemented error from overwritten class method

Tags: python, tensorflow, subclassing, keras-rl

I've been working on an RL agent to do the Taxi problem in openai gym.

I picked the DQNAgent from keras-rl and I am following along with the example here:

https://tiewkh.github.io/blog/deepqlearning-openaitaxi/

```
import gym
from gym import wrappers, logger
import numpy as np
import pickle
import json, sys, os
from os import path

from taxi import TaxiEnv

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Embedding, Reshape
from keras.optimizers import Adam

action_size = env.nA

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(500, 10, input_length=1))
model.add(Reshape((10,)))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(action_size, activation='linear'))
print(model.summary())

from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import EpsGreedyQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory

memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
policy = EpsGreedyQPolicy()

dqn_only_embedding = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=action_size, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=500, target_model_update=1e-2, policy=policy)
dqn_only_embedding.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])

#: I'm actually running this in jupyter so I use debug magic
%debug
dqn_only_embedding.fit(env, nb_steps=1000000, visualize=False, verbose=1, nb_max_episode_steps=99, log_interval=100000)
```

It seems to work for the better part of one batch.

```
Training for 1000000 steps ...
Interval 1 (0 steps performed)
   489/100000 [..............................] - ETA: 4:42 - reward: -1.3497
```

Then I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-e017660bd2c2> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('debug', '')
----> 2 dqn_only_embedding.fit(env, nb_steps=1000000, visualize=False, verbose=1, nb_max_episode_steps=99, log_interval=100000)

~Projects/RL/rl/core.py in fit(self, env, nb_steps, action_repetition, callbacks, verbose, visualize, nb_max_start_steps, start_step_policy, log_interval, nb_max_episode_steps)
    202                     # Force a terminal state.
    203                     done = True
--> 204                 metrics = self.backward(reward, terminal=done)
    205                 episode_reward += reward
    206 

~Projects/RL/rl/agents/dqn.py in backward(self, reward, terminal)
    325             # pdb.set_trace()
    326             ins = [state0_batch] if type(self.model.input) is not list else state0_batch
--> 327             metrics = self.trainable_model.train_on_batch(ins + [targets, masks], [dummy_targets, targets])
    328             metrics = [metric for idx, metric in enumerate(metrics) if idx not in (1, 2)]  # throw away individual losses
    329             metrics += self.policy.metrics

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics, return_dict)
   1725                                                     class_weight)
   1726       self.train_function = self.make_train_function()
-> 1727       logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1728 
   1729     if reset_metrics:

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    853       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    854       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 855       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    856     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    857       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

If I run without the debug magic I get a slightly different error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-d9e25a0a5e69> in <module>
      1 # %debug
----> 2 dqn_only_embedding.fit(env, nb_steps=1000000, visualize=False, verbose=1, nb_max_episode_steps=99, log_interval=100000)

~Projects/RL/rl/core.py in fit(self, env, nb_steps, action_repetition, callbacks, verbose, visualize, nb_max_start_steps, start_step_policy, log_interval, nb_max_episode_steps)
    202                     # Force a terminal state.
    203                     done = True
--> 204                 metrics = self.backward(reward, terminal=done)
    205                 episode_reward += reward
    206 

~Projects/RL/rl/agents/dqn.py in backward(self, reward, terminal)
    325             # pdb.set_trace()
    326             ins = [state0_batch] if type(self.model.input) is not list else state0_batch
--> 327             metrics = self.trainable_model.train_on_batch(ins + [targets, masks], [dummy_targets, targets])
    328             metrics = [metric for idx, metric in enumerate(metrics) if idx not in (1, 2)]  # throw away individual losses
    329             metrics += self.policy.metrics

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics, return_dict)
   1725                                                     class_weight)
   1726       self.train_function = self.make_train_function()
-> 1727       logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1728 
   1729     if reset_metrics:

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    870       initializers = []
--> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    872     finally:
    873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    723     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    726             *args, **kwds))
    727 

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2967       args, kwargs = None, None
   2968     with self._lock:
-> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2970     return graph_function
   2971 

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3359 
   3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3363 

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3194     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3195     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3196         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3197             self._name,
   3198             self._python_function,

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

/anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

NotImplementedError: in user code:

    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:757 train_step
        self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:498 minimize
        return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:631 apply_gradients
        return distribute_ctx.get_replica_context().merge_call(
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2941 merge_call
        return self._merge_call(merge_fn, args, kwargs)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2948 _merge_call
        return merge_fn(self._strategy, *args, **kwargs)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:682 _distributed_apply  **
        update_ops.extend(distribution.extended.update(
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2494 update
        return self._update(var, fn, args, kwargs, group)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3431 _update
        return self._update_non_slot(var, fn, (var,) + tuple(args), kwargs, group)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3437 _update_non_slot
        result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:653 apply_grad_to_update_var  **
        return self._resource_apply_sparse_duplicate_indices(
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1214 _resource_apply_sparse_duplicate_indices
        return self._resource_apply_sparse(summed_grad, handle, unique_indices,
    /anaconda3/envs/openai_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1236 _resource_apply_sparse
        raise NotImplementedError("Must be implemented in subclasses.")

    NotImplementedError: Must be implemented in subclasses.
```

In my DQNAgent, the backwards method is overwritten so I'm not sure why I'm seeing this.

```
class DQNAgent(AbstractDQNAgent):
    """
    # Arguments
        model__: A Keras model.
        policy__: A Keras-rl policy that are defined in [policy](https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/blob/master/rl/policy.py).
        test_policy__: A Keras-rl policy.
        enable_double_dqn__: A boolean which enable target network as a second network proposed by van Hasselt et al. to decrease overfitting.
        enable_dueling_dqn__: A boolean which enable dueling architecture proposed by Mnih et al.
        dueling_type__: If `enable_dueling_dqn` is set to `True`, a type of dueling architecture must be chosen which calculate Q(s,a) from V(s) and A(s,a) differently. Note that `avg` is recommanded in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06581).
            `avg`: Q(s,a;theta) = V(s;theta) + (A(s,a;theta)-Avg_a(A(s,a;theta)))
            `max`: Q(s,a;theta) = V(s;theta) + (A(s,a;theta)-max_a(A(s,a;theta)))
            `naive`: Q(s,a;theta) = V(s;theta) + A(s,a;theta)

    """
    def __init__(self, model, policy=None, test_policy=None, enable_double_dqn=False, enable_dueling_network=False,
                 dueling_type='avg', *args, **kwargs):
        super(DQNAgent, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Validate (important) input.
        if hasattr(model.output, '__len__') and len(tuple(model.output.shape)) > 2:
            raise ValueError('Model "{}" has more than one output. DQN expects a model that has a single output.'.format(model))
        if tuple(model.output.shape) != (None, self.nb_actions):
            raise ValueError('Model output "{}" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case {}.'.format(model.output, self.nb_actions))

        # Parameters.
        self.enable_double_dqn = enable_double_dqn
        self.enable_dueling_network = enable_dueling_network
        self.dueling_type = dueling_type
        if self.enable_dueling_network:
            # get the second last layer of the model, abandon the last layer
            layer = model.layers[-2]
            nb_action = model.output._keras_shape[-1]
            # layer y has a shape (nb_action+1,)
            # y[:,0] represents V(s;theta)
            # y[:,1:] represents A(s,a;theta)
            y = Dense(nb_action + 1, activation='linear')(layer.output)
            # caculate the Q(s,a;theta)
            # dueling_type == 'avg'
            # Q(s,a;theta) = V(s;theta) + (A(s,a;theta)-Avg_a(A(s,a;theta)))
            # dueling_type == 'max'
            # Q(s,a;theta) = V(s;theta) + (A(s,a;theta)-max_a(A(s,a;theta)))
            # dueling_type == 'naive'
            # Q(s,a;theta) = V(s;theta) + A(s,a;theta)
            if self.dueling_type == 'avg':
                outputlayer = Lambda(lambda a: K.expand_dims(a[:, 0], -1) + a[:, 1:] - K.mean(a[:, 1:], axis=1, keepdims=True), output_shape=(nb_action,))(y)
            elif self.dueling_type == 'max':
                outputlayer = Lambda(lambda a: K.expand_dims(a[:, 0], -1) + a[:, 1:] - K.max(a[:, 1:], axis=1, keepdims=True), output_shape=(nb_action,))(y)
            elif self.dueling_type == 'naive':
                outputlayer = Lambda(lambda a: K.expand_dims(a[:, 0], -1) + a[:, 1:], output_shape=(nb_action,))(y)
            else:
                assert False, "dueling_type must be one of {'avg','max','naive'}"

            model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=outputlayer)

        # Related objects.
        self.model = model
        if policy is None:
            policy = EpsGreedyQPolicy()
        if test_policy is None:
            test_policy = GreedyQPolicy()
        self.policy = policy
        self.test_policy = test_policy

        # State.
        self.reset_states()

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(DQNAgent, self).get_config()
        config['enable_double_dqn'] = self.enable_double_dqn
        config['dueling_type'] = self.dueling_type
        config['enable_dueling_network'] = self.enable_dueling_network
        config['model'] = get_object_config(self.model)
        config['policy'] = get_object_config(self.policy)
        config['test_policy'] = get_object_config(self.test_policy)
        if self.compiled:
            config['target_model'] = get_object_config(self.target_model)
        return config

    def compile(self, optimizer, metrics=[]):
        metrics += [mean_q]  # register default metrics

        # We never train the target model, hence we can set the optimizer and loss arbitrarily.
        self.target_model = clone_model(self.model, self.custom_model_objects)
        self.target_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
        self.model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

        # Compile model.
        if self.target_model_update < 1.:
            # We use the `AdditionalUpdatesOptimizer` to efficiently soft-update the target model.
            updates = get_soft_target_model_updates(self.target_model, self.model, self.target_model_update)
            optimizer = AdditionalUpdatesOptimizer(optimizer, updates)

        def clipped_masked_error(args):
            y_true, y_pred, mask = args
            loss = huber_loss(y_true, y_pred, self.delta_clip)
            loss *= mask  # apply element-wise mask
            return K.sum(loss, axis=-1)

        # Create trainable model. The problem is that we need to mask the output since we only
        # ever want to update the Q values for a certain action. The way we achieve this is by
        # using a custom Lambda layer that computes the loss. This gives us the necessary flexibility
        # to mask out certain parameters by passing in multiple inputs to the Lambda layer.
        y_pred = self.model.output
        y_true = Input(name='y_true', shape=(self.nb_actions,))
        mask = Input(name='mask', shape=(self.nb_actions,))
        loss_out = Lambda(clipped_masked_error, output_shape=(1,), name='loss')([y_true, y_pred, mask])
        ins = [self.model.input] if type(self.model.input) is not list else self.model.input
        trainable_model = Model(inputs=ins + [y_true, mask], outputs=[loss_out, y_pred])
        assert len(trainable_model.output_names) == 2
        combined_metrics = {trainable_model.output_names[1]: metrics}
        losses = [
            lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred,  # loss is computed in Lambda layer
            lambda y_true, y_pred: K.zeros_like(y_pred),  # we only include this for the metrics
        ]
        trainable_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses, metrics=combined_metrics)
        self.trainable_model = trainable_model

        self.compiled = True

    def load_weights(self, filepath):
        self.model.load_weights(filepath)
        self.update_target_model_hard()

    def save_weights(self, filepath, overwrite=False):
        self.model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=overwrite)

    def reset_states(self):
        self.recent_action = None
        self.recent_observation = None
        if self.compiled:
            self.model.reset_states()
            self.target_model.reset_states()

    def update_target_model_hard(self):
        self.target_model.set_weights(self.model.get_weights())

    def forward(self, observation):
        # Select an action.
        state = self.memory.get_recent_state(observation)
        q_values = self.compute_q_values(state)
        if self.training:
            action = self.policy.select_action(q_values=q_values)
        else:
            action = self.test_policy.select_action(q_values=q_values)

        # Book-keeping.
        self.recent_observation = observation
        self.recent_action = action

        return action

    def backward(self, reward, terminal):
        # Store most recent experience in memory.
        if self.step % self.memory_interval == 0:
            self.memory.append(self.recent_observation, self.recent_action, reward, terminal,
                               training=self.training)

        metrics = [np.nan for _ in self.metrics_names]
        if not self.training:
            # We're done here. No need to update the experience memory since we only use the working
            # memory to obtain the state over the most recent observations.
            return metrics

        # Train the network on a single stochastic batch.
        if self.step > self.nb_steps_warmup and self.step % self.train_interval == 0:
            experiences = self.memory.sample(self.batch_size)
            assert len(experiences) == self.batch_size

            # Start by extracting the necessary parameters (we use a vectorized implementation).
            state0_batch = []
            reward_batch = []
            action_batch = []
            terminal1_batch = []
            state1_batch = []
            for e in experiences:
                state0_batch.append(e.state0)
                state1_batch.append(e.state1)
                reward_batch.append(e.reward)
                action_batch.append(e.action)
                terminal1_batch.append(0. if e.terminal1 else 1.)

            # Prepare and validate parameters.
            state0_batch = self.process_state_batch(state0_batch)
            state1_batch = self.process_state_batch(state1_batch)
            terminal1_batch = np.array(terminal1_batch)
            reward_batch = np.array(reward_batch)
            assert reward_batch.shape == (self.batch_size,)
            assert terminal1_batch.shape == reward_batch.shape
            assert len(action_batch) == len(reward_batch)

            # Compute Q values for mini-batch update.
            if self.enable_double_dqn:
                # According to the paper "Deep Reinforcement Learning with Double Q-learning"
                # (van Hasselt et al., 2015), in Double DQN, the online network predicts the actions
                # while the target network is used to estimate the Q value.
                q_values = self.model.predict_on_batch(state1_batch)
                assert q_values.shape == (self.batch_size, self.nb_actions)
                actions = np.argmax(q_values, axis=1)
                assert actions.shape == (self.batch_size,)

                # Now, estimate Q values using the target network but select the values with the
                # highest Q value wrt to the online model (as computed above).
                target_q_values = self.target_model.predict_on_batch(state1_batch)
                assert target_q_values.shape == (self.batch_size, self.nb_actions)
                q_batch = target_q_values[range(self.batch_size), actions]
            else:
                # Compute the q_values given state1, and extract the maximum for each sample in the batch.
                # We perform this prediction on the target_model instead of the model for reasons
                # outlined in Mnih (2015). In short: it makes the algorithm more stable.
                target_q_values = self.target_model.predict_on_batch(state1_batch)
                assert target_q_values.shape == (self.batch_size, self.nb_actions)
                q_batch = np.max(target_q_values, axis=1).flatten()
            assert q_batch.shape == (self.batch_size,)

            targets = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.nb_actions))
            dummy_targets = np.zeros((self.batch_size,))
            masks = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.nb_actions))

            # Compute r_t + gamma * max_a Q(s_t+1, a) and update the target targets accordingly,
            # but only for the affected output units (as given by action_batch).
            discounted_reward_batch = self.gamma * q_batch
            # Set discounted reward to zero for all states that were terminal.
            discounted_reward_batch *= terminal1_batch
            assert discounted_reward_batch.shape == reward_batch.shape
            Rs = reward_batch + discounted_reward_batch
            for idx, (target, mask, R, action) in enumerate(zip(targets, masks, Rs, action_batch)):
                target[action] = R  # update action with estimated accumulated reward
                dummy_targets[idx] = R
                mask[action] = 1.  # enable loss for this specific action
            targets = np.array(targets).astype('float32')
            masks = np.array(masks).astype('float32')

            # Finally, perform a single update on the entire batch. We use a dummy target since
            # the actual loss is computed in a Lambda layer that needs more complex input. However,
            # it is still useful to know the actual target to compute metrics properly.
            # pdb.set_trace()
            ins = [state0_batch] if type(self.model.input) is not list else state0_batch
            metrics = self.trainable_model.train_on_batch(ins + [targets, masks], [dummy_targets, targets])
            metrics = [metric for idx, metric in enumerate(metrics) if idx not in (1, 2)]  # throw away individual losses
            metrics += self.policy.metrics
            if self.processor is not None:
                metrics += self.processor.metrics

        if self.target_model_update >= 1 and self.step % self.target_model_update == 0:
            self.update_target_model_hard()

        return metrics
...
```

I've tried digging around with the debugger but other than these two error messages I've not had much luck.  Is there some other method that I need to override that would potentially throw an error like this?